# How to Access Narrator Programmatically in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, text-to-speech, programmatically-created, narrator

How to Access CustomText in Xamarin.forms?
I'm trying to access narrator by referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/narrator-and-voice-input/2-audio-descriptions-with-narrator.
I'm facing difficulty in Accessing narrator Programmatically. If anyone know, kindly explain how to acccess narrator in Programmatically in xamarin.forms.

Comment: as with any platform native library, you should use DependencyService to access it from Forms shared code

Comment: Rasika I don't think I understood you completely. 

Since you added the tag of "Text to speech: you can use the "Text-to-speech" api from Xamarin.Essentials to access the speaking functionality https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/text-to-speech

Apart from that, if you are looking at using the "Narrator", it is called "VoiceOver" in iOS, and "TalkBack" in Android. You cannot turn them on programmatically, you have to turn it on in your phone's settings